# Filter local name from an email address

Tags: regex, shell, email, filter

I get a database from an email server containing something close to 3 millions of email addresses that were sent.

But, as you can imagine, most of this addresses are spam emails, and I trying to remove they from this list.

Filtering some domains and invalid formats using regular expressions, i reach 400145 remain addresses.

But, looking at the results, some emails like YSXCVZXFASDFKLS@gmail.com still on the list, because until now i didn't apply any filter based on the local name.

My question is: How can I filter the remaining email adresses based on the local name? I try to find a pattern, but are emails like pp3@gmail.com, Yaxv@hotmail.com, how can I differ this ones from the valid email addresses like ebcom@gmail.com?

Comment: Please specify technologies you're using

Comment: The list of emails is in a txt file for now, but to solve the problem I can use any method